# Applescript: insert text with Eñe

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to set up a text insertion service in Applescript using the following code:

```
on run
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "PIÑATA"
    end tell
end run
```

When I run the text it inserts "PlaATA" instead of "PIÑATA". What do I need to do for it to properly recognize the 'Ñ'?

Comment: On my keyboard (french !), I must  type first Alt N (to get the ~) and then shift N (to get the N). so keystroke "n" using {option down} and next line keystroke "N". just add before and after other characters.

Answer (score 0):

The keystroke command of System Events actually mimics the active keyboard. The way you type ñ on your keyboard is how you use the keystroke command to do so. For U.S., it ⌥n followed by n. Something like this should get you started.

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "PI"
    keystroke "n" using (option down)
    keystroke "n" using (shift down)
    keystroke "ATA"
end tell
```

That's whack, I know, but if you're just talking about ñ's with Spanish, you could write a routine that finds those and breaks up your string into strings between all the ennes and then cycle through that list with your keystroke commands.

Keystroke can not just take higher range unicode (even ascii) characters. You'll have to copy the text to the keyboard and then paste the text as an alternative method.